# ngx context menu with filtering ability

Tags: angular, ngx-contextmenu

Im using ngx context menu with angular 14 everything is working fine but my context menu can have huge amount of items at time so i added a search input at the top to allow the user to type the keyword and search from the large list.but i can't find a way to update the list while the context menu is still open. when i type a query in the search and close the context menu then open it again the filtering works but it does not while the context menu is still open.
here is the component that contains the context menu items

```
<context-menu #mergeFieldsContextMenu>
  <ng-template contextMenuItem [passive]="true" >
    <span class="p-input-icon-right w-100">
      <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
      <input 
       [(ngModel)]="searchMergeFieldText"
       type="text" 
       class="form-control w-100" 
       aria-label="search"
       aria-describedby="search"
       placeholder="Search merge field" />
    </span>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template contextMenuItem divider="true"></ng-template>
  <ng-template 
   *ngFor="let mField of menuItems | search: 'name': searchMergeFieldText" 
   contextMenuItem 
   let-item
   (execute)="mergeFieldClicked({mergeFieldText: mField.name,targetObject: $event.item.source,targetProperty: $event.item.targetProperty,editor: $event.item.editor})">
   {{mField.name}}
  </ng-template>
</context-menu>
```

I have a search Pipe that filter the items properly.

[image]

Comment: Could you add your code as well?

Comment: @AldinBradaric i have added the code in the post. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @AldinBradaric if you could create stackblitz that will be great